# How to get updated repo files while using checkout in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

We have a requirement to download all files from repo and update the file and repush to Azure Devops repo.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: e2e_fx
    type: git
    name: Azure/iot-sdks-e2e-fx
    ref: refs/heads/master

- checkout: git://Azure/iot-sdks-e2e-fx@refs/heads/master
  persistCredentials: true
```

The problem here is if multiple pipelines runs at the same time or they are in the queue it doesnt pick the latest that got pushed to master from the previous build anyway to get the files from latest commit or may be from rest API?

Comment: That could happen if the run of the previous pipeline has not finished and the code is not yet pushed on the repository. In general it's not a best practice to push code back to the repository from the build

Comment: @GeralexGR Nope the previous build has already made a commit in master but it usually picks the head when the actual build was started and not the time it's trying to checkout

Comment: @ElonMusk99 yes that is expected behavior in order to make your build run predictable. Have you tried to just run `git pull` in a script step?